# htaccess sub domain url rewriting is not taken into account

Tags: .htaccess, url, subdomain

I use the following code on the main domain (www.exemple.com) in a htaccess file to make url more friendly:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^seite-([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9])$   /index.php?page=$1 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*).html$   /post.php?id=$1
```

But this does not work on my subdomain (m.exemple.com). Same issue if I put a htaccess file in the subdomain folder.

Has someone a solution for that ?

Thanks in advance,

Oliver